# Why is the password requirement so strict for Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: discussion

Are the password restrictions really necessary? Are people storing their SSN and Bank Account info on Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, but an OpenID service is supposed to be used on other sites, too, where more sensitive info may be stored.